# How to use linux shell command to upload entire directory to ftp server?

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

I'm writing continuous integration script for Android，once the build task finished, I want to use a shell script to upload the entire output directory to ftp server.

I wonder is there has shell command like ftp or curl can do this, I searched a lots on the Google, but nothing found. Can anyone give me a favor? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You searched *a lot* on Google and didn't find an explanation how to upload a directory to `ftp`? Really?

Comment: Like this? `lftp -ulogin,passwd -e "mirror --reverse /my/from/dir/ /ftp/target/dir/" <ftp.server>` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use this command upload directory to ftp server successfully. Thanks again. @MarkSetchell

Comment: I have added it as an answer so it is easier to find and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for `lftp` like this:

```
lftp -u login,passwd -e "mirror --reverse /my/from/dir/ /ftp/target/dir/" <ftp.server>
```

Comment: lost a space between -u and login username. `lftp -u username,password -e "mirror --reverse /my/from/dir/ /ftp/target/dir/" <ftp.server>`